# Undertow + CompletableFuture/RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, undertow, completable-future

```
public class HelloWorldServer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
                    }
                }).build();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

It is hello world application using undertow. 
Can someone provide an example with Undertow + CompletableFuture or RxJava? I've searched but without success.

Comment: what functionality are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to handle requests what will query databases, so till database response I want to handle another request

Comment: please look at my answer here, you need to understand how to create observable from async callbacks:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225722/rxjava-data-from-db-with-onscreen-list/42226534#42226534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the undertow hello world with RxJava 2:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Observable<HttpServerExchange> exchangeObservable = Observable.create(observableEmitter -> {
        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        observableEmitter.onNext(exchange);
                    }
                }).build();
        server.start();
        observableEmitter.setCancellable(() -> server.stop());
    });

    exchangeObservable.subscribe(exchange -> {
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
    });
}
```

This is just a simplistic example, the hello world Undertow + RxJava, that doesn't take into account thread management among other stuff. I used `Observable.create()` to wrap the `HttpHandler` and it's callback to an `Observable`. This `Observable` represent the flow of incoming request that you will consume (the `exchangeObservable.subscribe()` part) to handle requests.

RxJava will only change the grammar from callback to observable pattern, plus offering a good set of operators to deal with them: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by thread management? Do you have some examples?

Comment: You can read at this subject http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html and the links given at the bottom. By default an Observable won't instantiate thread or use any mechanism of parallelism. Before jumping on RxJava Schedulers, look at how undertow work. Usually web server handle thread management for you.